# Winforms, creating padding when using Dock properties

Tags: c#, winforms, padding

How do I add padding, or some space between the textboxes when using dockstyle.top property?

```
for(int i =0; i< 10; i++) {
    textboxes[i] = new TextBox();
    textboxes[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    mypanel.Controls.Add(textboxes[i]); 
}
```

The code above puts textboxes right beneath each other. Can't figure this out without using mass panels or fixed positioning. How to do the following?

1) I would like to add around 10-20pixels between boxes.

2) How to change size (height,width) of the textboxes, since when using dockstyle.top it ignores the size commands ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With DockStype.Top you can't change the width of your TextBoxes, cause they are docked. You can only change the height. But to change the height of a TextBox you have to set the `Multiline = true` beforehand.

To get the space between the different boxes you have to put each TextBox within a panel, set the `TextBox.Dock = Fill`, the `Panel.Dock = Top` and the `Panel.Padding = 10`. Now you have some space between each TextBox.

#### Sample Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var panelTextBox = CreateBorderedTextBox();

    this.Controls.Add(panelTextBox);
}

private Panel CreateBorderedTextBox()
{
    var panel = CreatePanel();
    var textBox = CreateTextBox();

    panel.Controls.Add(textBox);
    return panel;
}

private Panel CreatePanel()
{
    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    panel.Padding = new Padding(5);

    return panel;
}

private TextBox CreateTextBox()
{
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Multiline = true;
    textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    return textBox;
}
```

What i forgot, you can also give a try to the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah8ywcc.aspx). Just remove the `DockStyle.Top` from the panels and put them into the FlowLayoutPanel. Also you should set the [FlowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection.aspx) to TopDown. Maybe this can also help you to solve your problem, too.

Comment: I was afraid I would be forced to do that. Thanks

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel is really great. I wanted to have two labels side-by-side where they grow left-to-right by pushing the control on front of, keeping both aligned and did jsut fine with FLP.

Answer (score 5):

Another work around that suits smaller layouts is to just add a `Label` control afterwards also docked to the `Top`, which is not AutoSized, `Text=" "`, `Height=your padding`. This is quite useful for the odd bit of padding when using the designer.

Answer (score 2):

I know where you're coming from, this is especially frustrating after returning to WinForms from WPF.

I would suggest using a [**TableLayoutPanel**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx), in which each TextBox would get its own cell, and adjusting the properties of the cells. This should solve both your padding and size problems.

Another alternative would be to use some more complex layout controls, such as the [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Layout/) ones (not free).

Comment: Will try tablelayoutpanel in the future. Thanks for the tip